# ORMLite LazyForeignCollection: How to query a collection only once?

Tags: ormlite

Let's assume I have the following object:

```
public class MyOwnList {

    @DatabaseField(id= true)
    protected int id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    protected Collection<Item> items;
}
```

As `items` is marked as lazy it won't be loaded if I load the list object from the database.
That's exactly what I want!!

The problem is  that everytime I access `items`, ORMLite makes a sql query to get the collection. Only discovered it after activating the logging of ORMLite...

Why does it do that? Any good reason for that?

Is there any way that I can lazy load the collection, but only once, not everytime I access the collection? So something between eager and lazy?

Comment: Well the name `List` was just for the example. I just changed it to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The problem is that everytime I access items, ORMLite makes a sql query to get the collection.

So initially I didn't understand this.  What you are asking for is for [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) to cache the collection of items after it lazy loads it the first time.  The problem with this as the default is that ORMLite has no idea how big your collection of `items` is.  One of the reasons why lazy collections are used is to handle large collections.  If ORMLite kept all lazy collections around in memory, it could fill the memory.

I will add to the TODO list something like `lazyCached = true` which does a hybrid between lazy and eager.  Good suggestion.

Comment: In the docu it says `If eager is set to true then the separate query is made immediately and the orders are stored as a list within the collection`
I am looking for a combination of lazy loading of the collection as soon as it is accessed the first time. But once the SQL query for this collection was made, store it as a list within the collection. 
This way I can have multiple LazyForeignCollections in my entity, but they don't cause additional sql queries like EagerForeignCollections, if the Collection is never accessed.

How did you overcome such an issue so far? Maybe some advice?

Comment: @d1rk Again, the problem is that the collection may be HUGE which may overwhelm the memory.  This is the way hibernate and other ORM libraries work.  Either you get eager or lazy.  I've added it to the TODO list.

Comment: @Gray Huge upvote for this TODO - I initially assumed Lazy collections worked this way ("lazyCached")... in part this was because I thought the issue with Eager was more about *database operations* than *memory consumption* ("a lot of database operations are going to happen whenever you query for A" - http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/ForeignCollectionField.html#maxEagerLevel() ). Any progress on the feature? Thanks for ORMLite!

Comment: 4.49 still isn't out, and I still don't see this great sounding feature in the changelog....

Comment: Yeah this won't be in 4.49.  Can you add an issue or (better) a pull request on github which implements it?  https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core